# Dynamic class member?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-4.5

Is it possible to use a dynamic class member?  For example

```
class blarg
{
public dynamic ctx = new ExpandoObject();
}
```

without also making blarg inherit (and implement) from `DynamicObject`?

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do. Please clarify the question. You can have a field of type `dynamic` in any class... what have you tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: With something like this, it's often easier to just fire up LINQPad or Visual Studio and try it...

Comment: I did and was getting compilation errors, hence the question, but I found the problem, I was adding the type to the dynamic declaration like so: public dynamic ExpandoObject ctx = new ExpandoObject();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fixed inheritance structure; firstly, `dynamic` can use reflection/meta-programming anyway, so you can just attach a regular class with members and it'll work - but you won't be able to add new members etc. Secondly, "all" you need to do to support full `dynamic` is implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` - not inherit something. The "all" is in quotes, because that isn't trivial. `DynamicObject` exists to do some of the heavy lifting for you, as does `ExpandoObject` for the cases when you just want a property-bag.

But since the callers aren't binding to any particular type (since they are using `dynamic`), frankly it isn't a huge problem to inherit from `DynamicObject`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can make a field or property `dynamic` within any class.

Inheriting from `DynamicObject` is only required (technically, you need to implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`, but this is typically done via `DynamicObject`) if you want your class itself to be dynamic.